# Regex - find word in string

Tags: regex, cpu-word, polish

I have a string: `prawy p pęknięty p zderzak pęknięcie` (it's Polish 
language)

I want to select all `p` (except "p" in words "pęknięty" and "peknięcie")

I've tried to do something like that: `\b(s*ps*)\b`, but it doesn't work properly. Any ideas?

Comment: So, all `p` letters at the beginning of words but those two specific words? Try `\bp(?!ęknię(?:ty|cie)\b)`

Comment: Yes, thank you all for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe,

```
\bp(?=[a-z]+|\s|$)
```

or

```
(?!pęknięcie|pęknięty)\bp
```

might simply work fine.

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/8G7BP8/1/)

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/zgReNd/1/)

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/8G7BP8/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/8G7BP8/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might use a negative lookahead and a character class:

```
\bp(?!([eę]knię(?:cie|ty)\b)
```

In parts

- `\bp` preceded by a word boundary
- `(?!` If what is directly on the right is not

  - `[eę]knię` Match `e` or `ę` followed by `knię`
  - `(?:cie|ty)\b` Match `cie` or `ty` and a word boundary
- `)` Close negative lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PIN8Ho/1)

Using a character class might match an invalid variation of `e` or `ę` in the words.

To match the words exactly you could match them between word boundaries

```
\bp(?!ęknięty\b|ęknięcie\b)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QRURxQ/1)